# Parent table always inserted Duplicate rows

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have following codes with transaction block.When i place a order my base table (`TBL_T_Orders`) always inserts 2 identical rows (duplicate rows with different `OrderId`'s). Details table `TBL_T_OrderItems` correctly inserted the items.

My code

```
public CartTotal InsertNewOrder(CartTotal cartTotal)
{
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                transaction = con.BeginTransaction();

                string orderQuery = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TBL_T_Orders] ([OrderCode],[OrderReceivedDate]) 
                                      OUTPUT INSERTED.OrderId
                                      VALUES (@OrderCode, @OrderReceivedDate)";
                cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(orderQuery);
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;

                db.AddInParameter(cmd, "OrderCode", DbType.Int32, cartTotal.OrderCode);
                db.AddInParameter(cmd, "OrderReceivedDate", DbType.DateTime,DateTime.Now);

                db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd, transaction);

                int OrderId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                foreach (var item in cartTotal.items)
                {
                    string orderItemsQuery = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TBL_T_OrderItems] ([OrderId], [ItemId]
                                               VALUES (@OrderId, @ItemId)";

                    cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(orderItemsQuery);
                    cmd.Transaction = transaction;

                    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "OrderId", DbType.Int32, OrderId);//temp
                    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "ItemId", DbType.String, item.ItemId);

                    db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd, transaction);
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

            return cartTotal;
}
```

Comment: Well, you do `db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd, transaction);` and directly after it, you do `int OrderId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` -- looks like you execute the insert twice.

Comment: @stickybit when i removed that item then shows the error "System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized.'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting duplicate entries because you are executing query twice. First time with `db.ExecuteNonQuery` and then second time with `cmd.ExecuteScalar();`.

Remove first one `db.ExecuteNonQuery` line. Then it will work perfectly.

Comment: When i removed that then exception returns like "System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized.'"

Comment: Add cmd.Connection = con;